# Automatically replace the default value for each function in module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been toying with `easygui` and I was wondering if there was any way to automatically override the `title`'s argument default value for each method if the method has such an argument.

For example I now can do:

```
import easygui

oldf = easygui.boolbox
def newf(title='mytitle', *args):
    oldf(title=title, *args)
easygui.boolbox = newf
```

Is there a more sophisticated and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
import easygui
import inspect
import functools

funcs = [f for f in easygui.__dict__.values() if callable(f)]
for func in funcs:
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    if 'title' in sig.parameters:
        newf = functools.partial(func, title='mytitle')
        setattr(easygui, func.__name__, newf)
```